# Crossroads and requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I'm having trouble getting a route to match using crossroads with requirejs. Well, it probably has nothing to do with requirejs, just thought I'd mention it.

This is what my code looks like:

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        /* use shims to define dependencies for modules. e.g.,
        'jquery.colorize': ['jquery'],
        'jquery.scroll': ['jquery'],
        */
        'crossroads': ['signals', 'can']
    },
    paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2",
        "can": "/scripts/can/amd/can",
        "can.fixture": "/scripts/can/amd/can/util/fixture",
        "signals": "/scripts/signals/signals",
        "crossroads": "/scripts/crossroads/crossroads"
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'crossroads', 'controllers/project'], function ($, crossroads, projectController) {
    var projectRoute = crossroads.addRoute('projects', function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('projects ready');
            $.when(ProjectModel.findAll()).then(function (projectResponse) {
                var projects = new SortList(projectResponse);
                console.log('doc ready projects=', projects);

                new ProjectsControl('#projects', {
                    projects: projects,
                    defaultSort: 'priority'
                });
            });
        });
    })
    console.log('matched: ', projectRoute.match(window.location.href));
});
```

The url that it's trying to match is `http://localhost:34382/projects` and the output of console.log is "matched: false"

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'crossroads' is an AMD module, I don't think you need to shim it. You need to shim 'signals'. If this is the cause of the problem, is something else. Your solution (using pathname + search) sounds very strange.

Comment: You're right, my shims property is empty now and it works fine. My solution may sound strange but I don't know of another way to get it to detect the route. I suppose cossroads may have been meant for single-page ajax applications that use the hash to load different pages but I want to use it in a multi-page application.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I need to change what I'm matching on. I've changed this line

```
console.log('matched: ', projectRoute.match(window.location.href));
```

to this

```
console.log('matched: ', projectRoute.match(window.location.pathname + window.location.search));
```

and now it works.

Also realized that you have to explicitly call crossroads.parse() somewhere for it to work (or am I missing something?)

so at the end of my require function I call this and my route is found

```
crossroads.parse(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Also, in case anyone is wondering, I'm using [CanJS](http://canjs.us/) as the client-side MVC framework and ASP.NET MVC4 as the server-side.